# ui-automation testin ios

Tags: iphone, ios4, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'm working for an iPhone project. I would like to use an UI Automation testing for my app. I'm completely new to testing.
 I went though this [document](http://alexvollmer.com/posts/2010/07/03/working-with-uiautomation/) its quiet easy to understand but it doesn't say so much about scripts. I'm new to AppleScript also. How should I go about? The script in this link shows errors for me.

Should I run the script in AppleScript editor or save in XCode with .js extension.
do help me with this?

What all UI can I test using automation testing tool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NativeDriver together with Selenium, may be of some help to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run Instruments (located in /Developer/Applications folder) and use Automation instrument. Set your app target and testing script there.

Answer (score 0):

You should check https://github.com/square/KIF is from the guys from Square I used in my proyects and works great!